# динамическая структура

Tags: c++, c

Здравствуйте. Допустим есть массив структуры.

```
struct Stackoverflow{
BYTE Some;
BYTE Much;
BYTE Feel;
}array1[200]
```

как можно объявить array2 с размером [x1*x2] в теле программы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct _Stackoverflow
{
    BYTE Some;
    BYTE Much;
    BYTE Feel;
} *Stackoverflow;

Stackoverflow so = calloc( sizeof(struct _Stackoverflow), 100 );
```

И топчись оно всё конём.

Answer (score 6):

Ответы на вопрос отличаются для C и C++.

Компилятор языка C может не позволить вам выделить на стеке массив не известного во время компиляции размера. Поддержка этого стандартом C11 объявлена необязательной. Поэтому в качестве универсального решения вам придётся выделять его в free store:

```
struct Stackoverflow* array = malloc(sizeof(struct Stackoverflow) * x1 * x2);
```

Из популярных компиляторов gcc и clang поддерживают динамические массивы на стеке, используя втихомолку `_alloca`, Visual Studio не поддерживает.

Для компиляторов с поддержкой динамических массивов (а наличие такой поддержки вы можете проверить через макрос `__STDC_NO_VLA__`) вы можете написать просто

```
struct Stackoverflow array[x1 * x2];
```

(что, согласитесь, намного проще и приятнее). Учтите, что данные при этом будут расположены на ограниченном по размеру стеке, а значит, при большом их объёме вы можете получить переполнение стека. Следите за случаем, когда вы не контролируете значения параметров, влияющих на размер.

---

В C++ правильно использовать `std::vector`, который поддерживает переменный размер:

```
std::vector<Stackoverflow> data(x1 * x2);
```

---

Отдельное спасибо участникам @klopp, @ixSci, @avp, принявшим участие в дискуссии и сделавшим ответ намного лучше.

Comment: Вообще, динамические массивы в C - ересь, IMHO. Как и их размещение в стеке - независимо от языка.

Comment: @VladD error C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "void *" в "Stackoverflow*"

Comment: В С как раз таки стандарт *позволяет* выделять динамический массив на стеке. Смотрите  [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). В С++ такого сделать нельзя, пока. Но это, насколько  понимаю, ненадолго

Comment: @ixSci: Это было в C99, но закончилось в C11. По вашей же ссылке: _although subsequently relegated in C11 to a conditional feature which implementations are not required to support_.

Comment: ну optional это не закончились, а лишь не обязательны к реализации(чего я не знал, кстати, спасибо). Тем не менее clang и gcc их поддерживают, а это львиная доля всех C программ.

Comment: @KappaPolice: Это вы небось пытаетесь скомпилировать компилятором C++, да? [Вот C](http://ideone.com/yQUU6g), а [вот C++](http://ideone.com/d2DODc).

Comment: @ixSci: Угу, я это и написал в ответе.

Comment: Всё таки нужно поправить про стандарт, стандарт C не запрещает динамических массивов на стеке и это не особенность gcc, это часть стандарта.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, я читаю «implementations are not required to support» как «не гарантировано стандартом».

Comment: @klopp, даже если динамические массивы на стеке в Си -- ересь, то это слишком удобно, чтобы их не использовать. Т.О. на компиляторы, которые их не поддерживают просто не стоит серьезно смотреть.

Comment: @ixSci: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @avp: Мне кажется, это противоречит идеологии C. Выделение динамического массива на стеке означает _одобрение_ неверного использования стека: реально большие структуры данных надо располагать в куче. Аргументация тут такая же, как и в `alloca`. Например, вот [дискуссия](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1018853/276994) (которая тем не менее не однозначно против).

Comment: " то это слишком удобно, чтобы их не использовать" - ага, а потом объявляют "молодые программисты" такую хрень на пару бегамайт, да ещё с только что освоенной рекурсией, и начинают топить окружающий мир идиотскими вопросами.

Comment: Не сочтите за придирки, но я всё же считаю Ваш ответ всё ещё не верным. Не нужно делать выводы из википедии, не лучшее место. Фраза *"В C, стандарт не позволит вам выделить на стеке массив не известного во время компиляции размера"* не верна в корне, т.к. стандарт C позволят это сделать, но не заставляет компилятор реализовывать этот функционал. Если компилятор не реализует VLA, то должен сообщить об этом через `__STDC_NO_VLA_`. Но тоже самое можно сказать про потоки и атомарные инструкции, которые стандарт не требует от компилятора.

Comment: Но это всё вовсе не означает, что стандарт не гарантирует работоспособность потоков и атомарных операций, просто они пошил на поводу у тех, кто не хочет этого делать, поэтому такие разрешения. Но, повторюсь, 2 основных компилятора поддерживают все фичи C11.

Comment: @VladD, само собой, речь о больших данных не идет. Просто программист должен хорошо понимать что и как он обрабатывает.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, смотрите, как я думаю. Если я напишу конформную стандарту программу, и откомпилирую её конформным стандарту компилятором, то она должна откомпилироваться. Это не так в случае использования VLA. Верно?

Comment: @avp: Я бы тысячу раз подписался под фразой "программист должен хорошо понимать что и как он обрабатывает".

Comment: Стандарт C, в этом плане вводит в ступор, я такого ещё не встречал, поэтому даже не знаю, что сказать. Но совершенно точно нельзя трактовать, как не поддерживаемое стандартом. Стандарт поддерживает и определяет эту фичу, но пользователь должен проверять `__STDC_NO_VLA_`, чтобы быть уверенным.

Comment: @ixSci: Мне кажется, стандарт налагает условия на семантику для случая, когда VLA поддерживаются. То есть "либо без VLA, либо VLA, но тогда по стандарту".

Comment: В этом случае можно говорить, что *компилятор* не позволит, стандарт всё равно позволяет. Хотя интересный прецедент стандарт C создаёт, надеюсь C++ таким заниматься не будет.

Comment: @ixSci: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Слушайте, стандарт-не стандарт... Лично меня, как много и часто юзающего C, из стандартов волнует только одна вещь: объявления переменных в блоках видимости. Остальное - сахар, на который да насрать, если честно. Все эти "нововведения" нафиг не нужны, IMHO.

Comment: А фразу всё-таки не изменили :) Предлагаю заменить "В C, стандарт не позволит вам выделить на стеке массив не известного во время компиляции размера" на "Компилятор языка C, который поддерживает стандарт C11, может не позволить вам выделить на стеке массив не известного во время компиляции размера"

Comment: @ixSci: Вроде сейчас стало лучше.

Comment: Не в тему, конечно, но тоже интересное расширение: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_tool_guides/linux_using_gnu_compiler_collection/constructing-calls.html  Позволяет делать врапперры к функциям в динамически загружаемых .so

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать new[], можно использовать `std::vector<Stackoverflow>`. Лично я бы сделал на векторе.